# Handle overlapping ingress paths

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I have one ingress which handles all requests to `my-domain.example.com/api` and forwards them to `backend-service/api`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: default-backend
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: my-domain.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Now I added this second ingress, which should only handle the sub-path `my-domain.example.com/api/log` and forward it to `logger-service/api`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: logger
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /log/$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: my-domain.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/log(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: logger-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

But this doesn't work reliable. The log of the ingress controller tells me, that the request to `my-domain.example.com/api/log` was forwarded to the `backend-service`. I guess the overlapping paths make it unpredictable.

How do I have to configure my ingresses if I have one service which should handle all defaults (`/api/`) and some other services which should handle specific sub-paths (`/api/log`)?

Answer (score 0):

Each path in an Ingress is required to have a corresponding path type. Paths that do not include an explicit [pathType](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) will fail validation.
The only supported wildcard character for the path field of an Ingress is the * character. The * character must follow a forward slash (/) and must be the last character in the pattern. For example, /, /foo/, and /foo/bar/* are valid patterns, but , /foo/bar, and /foo//bar are not.A more specific pattern takes precedence over a less specific pattern. If you have both /foo/ and /foo/bar/, then /foo/bar/bat is taken to match /foo/bar/.For more information about path limitations and pattern matching, see the [URL Maps documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map).

**Suggestion : For second ingress try by mentioning the path as /api/log* .**

As shown below

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  annotations: 
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: logger
spec: 
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules: 
    - 
      host: my-domain.example.com
      http: 
        paths: 
          - 
            backend: 
              service: 
                name: logger-service
                port: 
                  number: 8080
            path: /api/log*
            pathType: Prefix
```

Above YAML is working, find below Screenshot :

[image]

Additional reference doc :
[Link1](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120#issuecomment-322007251)
[Link2](https://%20https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services)